# chart.js - Can we update the legend label if user click any data from dataset?

Tags: javascript, html, charts

my query is can we update the specifi lable font size and color if user click any specific portion of doughnut chart. like below

[image]

in above image as use can see, if user click on Green poriton of doughnut then want change the color/size of corresponding legend label, is this possible?

sample code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-shannon-ogr0in?file=/index.html)

```
   // config
      const config = {
        type: "doughnut",
        data: {
          labels: ["Green", "Red", "Blue"],
          datasets: [
            {
              data: [60, 80, 100],
              borderWidth: 0,
              backgroundColor: ["#009900", "#ff0000", "#3399ff"],
              hoverBackgroundColor: ["#009900", "#ff0000", "#3399ff"],
              cutout: "80%"
            }
          ]
        },
        options: {
          plugins: {
            legend: {
              position: "right",
              labels: {
                font: {
                  size: 11
                },
                usePointStyle: true,
                pointStyle: "circle"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      };
```

```
      // render init block
      const myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart"), config);
```